# Using angular-fullstack ngTable sort missing when deployed to Heroku

Tags: angularjs, heroku, ngtable, angular-fullstack

Here's an interesting one, I used angular-fullstack to build my app and created a table using ngTable. The table has a filter and sorting, that work perfectly fine when I serve it locally, but when I deploy it to Heroku, the table works fine, filters as expected with no errors, but the sorting is gone. No errors whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the attribute `sortable` to `data-sortable` fixed it for me.

Found the fix here:
https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/issues/418

Answer (score 0):

Found what the problem is, there is a weird overlay of data-title tag between bootstrap and ngtables that usemin apparently overwrites when the usemin tasks creates the css. If you create the headers manually the issue is resolved.